# Расположение элементов на странице shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

Не могу понять как расположить элементы, на странице что бы tabBox был под box(загрузка файла), таблица занимала всё пространство справа

Код

```
fluidRow(
      box(width = 3,
        fileInput(NS(id,"file"), "Загрузить файл", 
        buttonLabel = 'Загрузить', placeholder = 'Файл не выбран')),

      box(width = 9,dataTableOutput(NS(id,'outTable'))),
      
      tabBox(width = 3,
        tabPanel('column',
        useShinyjs(),
        hidden(checkboxGroupInput(NS(id,"select_column"),'Колонки', choices = ''))),
        tabPanel('drop',h2('drop value in table'))
      )
    )
```

[image: Желаемый результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно ограничить кол-во столбцов функцией column, и в ней box()/tabBox() 12 - использовать всё пространство которое указано в column.

Получил желаемый результат

```
fluidRow(
  column(3,
     box(width = 12,
         fileInput(NS(id,"file"), "Загрузить файл", 
                   buttonLabel = 'Загрузить', placeholder = 'Файл не выбран')),  
      tabBox(width = 12,
        tabPanel('column',
          useShinyjs(),
          hidden(checkboxGroupInput(NS(id,"select_column"),'Колонки', choices = ''))),
        tabPanel('drop',checkboxInput(NS(id,'drop_na'), 'drop na') )
      )
  ),
  column(9,
    box(width = 12,dataTableOutput(NS(id,'outTable')))
  )
```